# Checking if binary tree is a BST

Tags: java, recursion, graph, tree

I am confused by the following algorithm:

```
public static boolean checkBST(TreeNode n) {
    if (n == null) {
        return true;
    }

    // Check / recurse left
    if (!checkBST(n.left)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check current
    if (last_printed != null && n.data <= last_printed) {
        return false;
    }
    last_printed = n.data;

    // Check / recurse right
    if (!checkBST(n.right)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I understand the in-order traversal, and understand comparing the left child of the current node to make sure it's <= to the parent in the line with n.data <= last_printed, but where in this recursion do we check whether the right child is greater than the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right child is checked in the same way and place as the left child.

The algorithm works as if by printing the value of each node via an in-order traversal, and then checking whether the resulting list is in order.  Instead of actually printing, however, it maintains in instance variable `last_printed` the value that *would have been* most recently printed at that point in the traversal.  Regardless of the progression through the traversal and the path to the current node, the test marked `// Check current` performs the correct test for whether the current node is traversed in an order consistent with the tree being a BST.

The key thing to note is perhaps that `last_printed` is updated at the point were the current node is traversed, between traversing the left subtree and the right subtree.

Answer (score 0):

What do your left and right methods do? Are you just trying to verify that you have a binary search tree?